# smptclient: sending mails using emails saved in membership table

Tags: c#, .net

I am working in a feature where the user is able to send mail using a asp.net webApp. The idea is send mail using address saved in their membership table. With the current code bellow what i am getting are sent mails using the address testUser@gmail.com, but what i want is send mails using the email address stored in the membership table.
Thank in advance.

```
   var email = new MailMessage(mailContent.From, mailContent.To, mailContent.Subject, mailContent.Body);

   public static SendEmailResult SendEmail(MailMessage message)
    {
        message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        var mailClient = new SmtpClient();
        var log = new SendEmailResult() { Message = message };
        try
        {
            mailClient.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Exception = ex;
        }

        return log;
    }
```

My web config

```
  <system.net>
     <mailSettings>

       <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
         <network enableSsl="true"
           defaultCredentials="false"
           host="smtp.gmail.com"
           port="587"
           userName="testUser@gmail.com"
           password="myultrasecretpassword" />
       </smtp>

     </mailSettings>
 </system.net>
```

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: Not a fix but take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782409/mail-sending-with-users-email-as-sender

Comment: @JohnSaunders thank you for your nice feedback helping to improve question. btw  I don't agree with you about the effort in the question.

Comment: You didn't show any attempt to set the address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately I think it's not possible to just send an e-mail in the name of someone else (using someone else's credentials).

1. As @DGibbs shows, you'd need to know the credentials of the particular user. But you don't have the password.
2. The SMTP protocol alone wouldn't prevent you to use any kind of sender e-mail address in the "From" field, but the .NET `SmtpClient` will throw an exception (`SmtpException` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc.aspx).
3. The `SmtpClient` actually will only willing to send the e-mail if the running software's (or provided by NetworkCredentials) credentials match the from address's user.
4. If you use `UseDefaultCredentials`, the credentials (of the default) should still match the e-mail address's user and should be authorized.
5. What you can do is to setup a mail account for the purpose of automated mail. Even in this case there's a good chance that the software will run in the name of some other user, so system administrator has to configure that automated mail account in the mail server so that it would willing to let the software's user to send in the name of the automated account. The automated mail's subject or body can reference the user's name and e-mail if you like.

All of this is because today there are lot of mechanisms exist to prevent spamming. The system prevents you even from yourself to do anything which wouldn't be a good idea. Sending an e-mail in whoever's name is not a good idea from security point of view, even if the business requirements would require it.

`System.Net.Mail` provides a very clean and nice interface and API, but you have to work around the usage what you want. I've been there, done that. I mean the same situation.

Comment: thank you for your didactic explanation! :) very clear! :) i will add the correct email address inside of the body of the mail. thank you again.

Comment: I must add that my experiences I described are from a classical Windows Domain Controlled ActiveDirectory environment with an Exchange server. Many things can depend on your server settings though, but I'm sure the sys admin won't weaken the settings, otherwise spammers can find configuration holes easily and the company's SMTP server will be blacklisted.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the users details from the Membership table (it's up to you to do this) you can specify some credentials for the SMTP client before sending:

```
var mailClient = new SmtpClient();
mailClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
//etc...
```

Comment: yep... hummm i can understand what the only way to make it possible is know the username and password of the the user... in some point i I believed that i could create a mail using any email adress...